# Why are post requests not working and getting redirected?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, plesk

I am a beginner with laravel and vue and I have a problem with routes
when I make post requests to the server it tells me that the request was redirected, and I don't know where the problem is since the get requests work normally, please help me

vue code

```
 await this.form.post('/api/add_tramite/').then(response=>{
                console.log(response.data);
                this.fecthtramitesper();
                this.close();
          })
```

my route in laravel

```
Route::post('add_tramite',[tramiteController::class,'agregar_tramite']);
```

Comment: It should be noted that this problem only occurs on the plesk server, but on my PC it works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the trailing `/` in your URI.

```
await this.form.post('/api/add_tramite').then(response=>{
```

many servers redirect any url with trailing slash to the version without the slash for different reasons, one of them being SEO.